# How does Flask knows which decorated function to call?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

So I'm going through the basic Flask tutorial, and looking at their code there's this snippet:

```
 @app.teardown_appcontext
 def close_db_connection(exception):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        top.sqlite_db.close()
```

Now, for what I've read in their manual, the function "app.teardown_appcontext" is called whenever one of the callbacks has an unexpected behavior. Decorating a function with it allows you to add functionality to the original function. Or at least that's what I understand from decorators. But, if I do this:

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def stack_overflow_rocks(exception):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        top.sqlite_db.close()
```

It still works. How does Flask manages this?

My guess is that when I run the "flaskr.py" file with all the main code, it associates whatever decorated function with their code to call it when necessary. I tried reading a lot of sources about decorator to see if my interpretation is wrong, but could not find any mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [the code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py), the decorator adds the function you decorate with it to a list of functions (`self.teardown_appcontext_funcs`) on a `Flask` object instance (`app` in your case).  This list is then iterated over in reverse order when the appcontext is torn down, with each function being passed the exception triggering the teardown, or a placeholder exception if none was raised.  This happens in `Flask.do_teardown_appcontext()`.

Comment: Great explanation, everything makes sense now. Thanks!